# CSS Border style combobox or datefield extjs

Tags: css, extjs

I would like to "graphically disable" a combobox in extjs by appling a CSS class to remove the borders while the user does not click on it.

How can I apply this CSS class? It is not the border of the field but of a wrapper which wrap both field and picker.

(I have the same problem for datefield)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ext applies special CSS classes when fields are focused, so that's rahter easy to do focus-dependent styling. Use dev tools to explore the markup and see what you need to change.

For example, for removing all visual clues that it is a field from a combo that is not focused, use this CSS ([example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uC7av/)):

```
.custom-combo .x-form-field:not(.x-field-form-focus) {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background: none;
}

.custom-combo .x-form-item-body:not(.x-form-trigger-wrap-focus) .x-form-trigger {
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

I use `border: 1px solid transparent` instead of `border: 0` to prevent a 1px offset when the combo get focused.

Comment: My mistake was not to understand CSS : .a .b{attribute:val;} means "modify 'b' class which is in a 'a' class". Now it becomes easy to modify specific css.Thanks!